# How to open target="_blank" full screen?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to open new page with full screen. Below size is the my screen resolution. Still I have to click on re-sizable button on the browser to expand it to full screen.

How do I open it fill screen without clicking on re-sizeble?

```
Helper.Redirect("resource.aspx", "_blank",
                  "menubar=0,scrollbars=1,width=1366,height=768,top=10")
```

Method

```
Public Shared Sub Redirect(url As String, target As String, windowFeatures As String)
    Dim context As HttpContext = HttpContext.Current

    If ([String].IsNullOrEmpty(target) OrElse target.Equals("_self", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) AndAlso [String].IsNullOrEmpty(windowFeatures) Then

        context.Response.Redirect(url)
    Else
        Dim page As Page = DirectCast(context.Handler, Page)
        If page Is Nothing Then
            Throw New InvalidOperationException("Cannot redirect to new window outside Page context.")
        End If
        url = page.ResolveClientUrl(url)

        Dim script As String
        If Not [String].IsNullOrEmpty(windowFeatures) Then
            script = "window.open(""{0}"", ""{1}"", ""{2}"");"
        Else
            script = "window.open(""{0}"", ""{1}"");"
        End If

        script = [String].Format(script, url, target, windowFeatures)
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, GetType(Page), "Redirect", script, True)
    End If
End Sub
```

I tried `'fullscreen=yes, scrollbars=yes,location=yes,resizable=yes'` parameters. It did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
window.open('newWin.html','NewWindow','fullscreen=yes');
```

Source:

[Here](http://forums.devshed.com/javascript-development/98311-window-maximum-size-javascript-someones-age-post434087.html#post434087)

Comment: it did not work. vertical bar showing not full screen.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem is simples just change this

```
Dim script As String
    If Not [String].IsNullOrEmpty(windowFeatures) Then
        script = "window.open(""{0}"", ""{1}"", ""{2}"");"
    Else
        script = "window.open(""{0}"", ""{1}"");"
    End If
```

For this:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(windowFeatures))
            {
                script = @"var w = window.open(""{0}"", ""{1}"", ""{2}""); w.moveTo(0,0); w.resizeTo(screen.width,screen.height-40);";

            }
            else
            {
                script = @"var w = window.open(""{0}"", ""{1}""); w.moveTo(0,0); w.resizeTo(screen.width,screen.height-40);";
```

if you want to is just put the property resizeto and moveTo